# That's the last thing (about which) i want to go to bed thinking (about).-- grammaticality

Tags: grammaticality

> **A.** That's the last thing i want to go to bed thinking about.
>
> **B.** That's the last thing about which i want to go to bed thinking.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Not with that lower-case "i", no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both are grammatically correct, A sounds more natural.

Few people use "about which" in everyday speech.